# Typing hebrew in a text editor

Tags: text-editor, hebrew

I can't seem to find a text editor which behaves correctly in regards to bi-directional text. I type a lot in hebrew, with some english mixed in. In most of the apps I've tried (google docs, and mobisoft office suite), it doesn't render the spacing correctly and therefore you can't read the text as you're typing.

I started using VerbTeX, which has a simple text editor that works surprisingly well in this regard, but it gets slow and can't save to my external SD card.

If anyone knows a way that I can get my text files to display properly while I type them, it would be very helpful.